# Cloud 9 returns error: listen EADDRINUSE 0.0.0.0:8080

Tags: node.js, cloud9

I am using Cloud 9 for developing my nodeJS apps. When I am trying to start my app, I am getting this error "EADDRINUSE 0.0.0.0:8080". I have tried running "killall node" command to kill any processes running on this port. But I am still getting this error. Below is my stack trace.

**Stack trace**

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE 0.0.0.0:8080
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:907:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:930:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1250:14)
    at listen (net.js:1286:10)
    at net.js:1395:9
    at nextTickCallbackWith3Args (node.js:469:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:375:17)
    at Module.runMain [as _onTimeout] (module.js:443:11)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:92:15)
```

Comment: Could you run this command `netstat -tulpn`? It prints ports and process names. You can check 8080 port.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered with the same error.
If u are using ip and port again which is already used show this error.
for eg:

```
**server.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP,);
app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP, function(){
    console.log("Server has started");
});**
```

In that case you should remove one i.e.

```
**server.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP, function(){
    console.log("Server has started");
});**
```

Now you are done